# How to apply a condition only if an optional is present?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, option-type, predicate

I have an `Optional<LocalDate>` object and a `Stream` of other dates.

```
Stream<LocalDate> dates = ...;   
Optional<LocalDate> dateOptional = ...;
```

I would like to filter out all dates which are after the optional. If the optional is not present, the filter should not do anything.

I have written the `Predicate` like this:

```
Predicate<LocalDate> predicate = date -> !dateOptional.isPresent() || !date.isAfter(dateOptional.get());  
Stream<LocalDate> filteredStream = dates.filter(predicate);
```

I would like to avoid using `isPresent()` and `get()`. Is there a more functional way of writing the same logic? I am using Java 8.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The point is that the `Predicate<T>` must return an expression that always results in a `boolean`.

Since the `Localdate::isAfter` returns `boolean` you can use is with the advantage of `Optional` inside the `Predicate<LocalDate>` and result in `boolean`:

```
Optional<LocalDate> dateOptional = ...;
                                                        // Together Predicate<LocalDate>
Predicate<LocalDate> predicate = date -> dateOptional   // .. Optional<LocalDate>
     .map(d -> !date.isAfter(d))                        // .. Optional<Boolean>
     .orElse(true);                                     // .. Boolean


Stream<LocalDate> filteredStream = dates.filter(predicate);
```

Don't forget, the `Stream<LocalDate>` remains open until the terminal operation.

---

**Edit:** Thanks to [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger): The whole `predicate` might be optimized to avoid repetitively and unnecessary calls:

```
Predicate<LocalDate> predicate = dateOptional                 // Optional<LocalDate>
    .<Predicate<LocalDate>>map(d -> date -> !date.isAfter(d)) // Optional<Predicate<LocalDate>>
    .orElse(date -> true);                                    // Predicate<LocalDate>
```

Comment: The `Optional::filter` returns the same `Optional<LocalDate>` and allows filtering by a criterion. We want to use `Optional::map` because we need the `boolean` result of the `!date.isAfter(d)` method for the `Predicate`. Moreover, the methods `filter` and `map` results in `Optional.empty()` if the input is not present - so there is no need for `Optional::get`.

Comment: Shouldn't the predicate's default result be `true` instead of `false`? It seems to me that your solution will only work correctly if the date is present. Otherwise it will filter everything, resulting in an empty stream.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I have corrected my answer.

Comment: This is performing unnecessary operations. Since the `Optional` doesn’t change during the stream operation (it isn’t even allowed to change), you don’t need to repeatedly test the optional’s presence for every stream element. Instead, use `Predicate<LocalDate> predicate = dateOptional.<Predicate<LocalDate>>map(d -> date -> !date.isAfter(d)).orElse(date -> true);` You could even go a step further and not chain a `filter` operation to the stream when the optional is empty: `Stream<LocalDate> filteredStream = dateOptional .map(d -> dates.filter(date -> !date.isAfter(d))) .orElse(dates);`

Comment: Very good points. Thanks a lot. You might want to post your own answer with the whole Stream?

Comment: This question has been closed

Comment: That last edit is exactly the answer I provided :) That's the right approach IMHO, I'll remove mine to avoid duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I find for problems like this that it is almost always acceptable to use [`LocalDate.MIN`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#MIN), because it results in the simplest, most readable code.

```
LocalDate date = getOptionalDate().orElse(LocalDate.MIN);
dateStream.filter(d -> !d.isAfter(date));
```

There is a slight edge case where if your stream contains a value equal to `LocalDate.MIN` then it will be included when it should not have been. Given that `LocalDate.MIN` represents the year ~100 billion BCE, this edge case is for all intents and purposes irrelevant for most applications

Comment: I agree that for this particular problem this is a good way to get rid of the optional in the first place. However, it's kind of a hack for a very specific use case and doesn't answer the original question in a universal way.

Comment: @KrohnicDev Disagree that it's a "very specific use case". This works for most `Comparable` types where there is a defined minimum, i.e. all numbers, all timestamps, probably others.

Comment: Hmm, you say yourself that this doesn’t work when the stream contains the minimum, so it is a very specific use case, where the minimum is far outside the value range we can expect. For other values (the minimum of strings is just an empty string, the minimum of `enum` types is their first constant), the minimum is not such an unusual value and for yet another types (BigInteger, BigDecimal), the minimum is not representable in memory.

Comment: @Holger Please read the comment above yours.

Comment: @Michael I did read them and wrote precisely, why I disagree with your comment. This does *not* work “for most Comparable types where there is a defined minimum”. I named counter-examples. We can even narrow it down, i.e. you wrote “all numbers”, but for a `Stream<Byte>`, you can not assume that the smallest `Byte` will never appear in the stream.

Comment: @Holger BigInteger, BigDecimal and String don't have *defined* minimums. There is no `BigInteger.MIN`, `String.MIN`, etc.

Comment: So you say, a minimum is only defined when there is a static constant in the class? That’s nonsense. The empty string *is* the smallest string, it doesn’t need a `String.MIN` constant. Likewise, every `enum` type has a smallest value. I don’t know whether you ignored `Byte` because `Byte.MIN_VALUE` is a `byte` rather than `Byte`, but anyway, “all numbers” is an interesting claim, given how you are now ruling out most numbers…

Comment: @Holger Now you are strawman-ing; I didn't say a static constant was the only way something can be defined. I ignored byte because your example didn't make any sense. Byte is not special. This approach works if you can reasonably expect your data to be in a certain range. You seem to be implying that a stream of bytes will always use the full range, which is obviously not true. Whether you can reasonably expect your data to be in a certain range completely depends on the data.

Comment: You didn’t say it literally but were implying it by claiming there was no defined minimum for `String` because there is no `String.MIN`. What else was that supposed to say? Likewise, you ignored the `enum` example and now, you are reversing your statement. Yes, your solution “works if you can reasonably expect your data to be in a certain range” where “certain” means “not including the minimum”. This is precisely what the OP said, it’s “for a very specific use case” and not a universal solution. It’s reasonable to assume that `LocalDate.MIN` is uncommon but that does not work for other types.

Comment: @Holger "*[you] were implying it*" Nope, you inferred it (incorrectly). The whole concept of enums having ordinals is a design flaw of Java, since it implies a natural ordering where none may exist. It seems fundamentally that you and I disagree on the meaning "very specific". To me, something is not "very specific" just because it is "not universal". I can agree that this solution is somewhat specific, but I know from experience that it is not "very specific" because I have found plenty of use for it myself. There was already an answer showing the more verbose, more comprehensive approach 1/2

Comment: 2/2 so I thought I would show an alternative approach which lets you solve certain problems in a more elegant way. I added the appropriate caveat to my answer so there should be no confusion about which cases it should be avoided. What do you hope to gain from arguing about it? For me to delete it? If you wish to express your dislike for this approach, you have the means to vote on it.